# gradient of a concave function

Tags: calculus, convex-analysis, vector-analysis

Let $f\colon \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous, differentiable and concave function. Consider two arrays $\mathbf{y}, \mathbf{z} \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Suppose that it holds $f(\mathbf{z}) \leq f(\mathbf{y})$. Prove that it holds $\left \lvert \frac{d}{dx_i}f(\mathbf{y}) \right \rvert  \leq \left \lvert \frac{d}{dx_i}f(\mathbf{z})\right \rvert $ for all $i = 1, \dots, n$. If the claim is false, please provide a counterexample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Counterexample :

Let $f(x,y) = -x^2 - y^2$.

And define $\mathbf{y}:=(1,0)$ and $\mathbf{z}:=(0,2)$.
Then $f(\mathbf{z}) < f(\mathbf{y})$.

$\left \lvert \frac{d}{dx}f(\mathbf{y}) \right \rvert = 2$.

$\left \lvert \frac{d}{dx}f(\mathbf{z})\right \rvert = 0$.